# can I use the to_char function in where clause in a query with PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, date, plsql, dayofweek

I am trying to find out average of electricity volume of certain day in a week with the following query:

```
SELECT avg(volume)
FROM v_nem_rm16
WHERE to_char(day, 'day') = 'monday';
```

where the v_nem_rm16 is a table and volume, day are its columns and my query is returning null whatever I change the day value 'monday', 'tuesday',....

is this query wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually 'DAY' is returned with padding spaces on the right side.
If you use 'RTRIM' then you can avoid the null values.

```
SELECT avg(volume)
FROM v_nem_rm16
WHERE RTRIM(to_char(day, 'day')) = 'monday';
```

Comment: thank you very much, It works perfect and I've learnt another new thing again

Comment: alternatively, use `to_char(day, 'fmday')`

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use different date format to_char DAY is nls-dependent that is bad (for instance your software will fail in Spain). D returns number so in your case the query should look like

```
SELECT avg(volume)
FROM v_nem_rm16
WHERE RTRIM(to_char(day, 'd')) = 1;
```

Comment: well, that is a good way to avoid unnecessary errors, thanks a lot, btw, can you correct me if I am wrong: does 1 stand for Monday, 2 stand for Tuesday,...,7 stand for Sunday?

Comment: my fault - 'D' is nls-dependend as well, in order to make your plsql stable you may use RTRIM(to_char(day, 'day', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=american')) = 'monday' with explicit mentioning of NLS character set